# Pagination prev and next in a loop using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working on pagination on click next increment and prev decrement the result value. I have tried like this can anyone suggest me How to do.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var num = 5;
  $('.prev').on('click', function() {
    alert('dsdsd');
    for (var i = 0; i <= num.length; i--) {
      console.log(num);
      $('.result').append(num);
    }
  });

  $('.next').on('click', function() {
    for (var i = 0; i <= num.length; i++) {
      $('.result').append(num);
    }

  });
});
```

```css
.prev,
.next {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="prev">prev </div>
<div class="next">next</div>
<div class="result"></div>
```

Comment: What is your error? Also `.length` is not a property of an integer. Did you mean to just use `num` in your loops?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
   var maxRecords=5;
   $('.result').html(1);
  $('.prev').on('click', function() {
    var num = $('.result').text();
    num=num-1;
    if(num>0) {
         $('.result').html(num);
    } else{
        num=maxRecords;
         $('.result').html(num);
     }
  });

  $('.next').on('click', function() {
    var num = parseInt($('.result').text());
    num=num+1;
    if(num<=maxRecords){
        $('.result').html(num);
    }else{
      num=1;
      $('.result').html(num);
    }

  });
});
```

```css
.prev,
.next {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="prev">prev </div>
<div class="next">next</div>
<div class="result"></div>
```

Try this.

Comment: when prev comes at 1 then on next check come to the 5 like this 5,4,3,2,1,5..... in a loop.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need for loop for this just increase or decrease num on button clicks

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var num = 5;
  $('.prev').on('click', function() {
    alert('dsdsd');
   
   num--;
   $('.result').text(num);
  });

  $('.next').on('click', function() {
    num++;
   $('.result').text(num);

  });
});
```

```css
.prev,
.next {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="prev">prev </div>
<div class="next">next</div>
<div class="result"></div>
```

Comment: I want to loop up 5 only not more than 5 after 5 then prev 1,2,3,4,5